# jQuery scroll to top of DIV that is opening

Tags: jquery, scroll, accordion

I have an accordion that opens and closes open clicking. The problem I have is that I want the page to scroll to the top of div when it's clicked on. What I have doesn't quite work, it scrolls to where the top of div was when clicked on, not where it is. My jQuery code is:

```
$(".aro > .wrap").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(".active .details").slideUp("slow");
        $(".aro").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideUp("slow");
        }
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

I made a simple JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/489Y2/1/
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `animate` method is being fired while the `slideDown` is still running, thus it is taking the position at that point in time as where it should scroll to.

The easiest way to fix this is to place the `animate` into a callback that runs after the `slideDown` is completed like so:

```
$(".aro > .wrap").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(".active .details").slideUp("slow");
        $(".aro").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideDown("slow", function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/489Y2/6/).

Note that I have updated the selector from which the code obtains the offset top, as `$(this)` within the callback refers to `$(".details")`.