# How to auto scroll this accordion to the top of the selected heading and position it in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion that contains some long list of items.  I wish to mimic the same effect featured in the answer to [jQuery scroll to top of DIV that is opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772195/jquery-scroll-to-top-of-div-that-is-opening) provided by "winterblood".  I have already achieved this effect.  However, when I specify a height and attach a vertical scroll bar to it, in order to size it and position it on my web page, the auto scrolling to the top of the selected panel does not work.  It either has no effect and continues to occupy the entire browser window or it instead of scrolling to top of the selected panel, it stops midway of the list items

```js
$(window).load(function(){
$(".category > .equip").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
        $(".active .details").slideUp("slow");
        $(".category").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideDown("slow", function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().children(".details").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}


#accordian {position: relative;
 top: 200px;
 left: 20px;
 height: 400px;
 width: 250px;
 overflow-y: auto;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: #006F70;
 margin: 0px 16px 0 16px;
 color: white;
  /*Some cool shadow and glow effect*/
 box-shadow: 
  0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
  0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid white;
}
/*heading styles*/
#accordian h3 {
 font-size: 12px;
 letter-spacing: 0.7px;
 word-spacing: 1px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 line-height: 17px;
 white-space: pre-line;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
 background: #003040; 
 background: linear-gradient(#003040, gray);
}
 
/*heading hover effect*/
#accordian h3:hover {background: #008080;}
 /**text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 128 128, 0.5.);**/
}

/*list items*/
#accordian li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
/*links*/
#accordian ul ul li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 white-space: pre-line;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 11px;
 line-height: 27px;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 15px;
 /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
 transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
#accordian ul ul li a:hover {
 background: #003545;
 border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#accordian ul ul {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="accordianFABQtest-GS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="accordian">
 <ul>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 1</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 2</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 3</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 4</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 5</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 6</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 24</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 25</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="category">
   <h3 class="equip">Panel 7</h3>
   <ul class="details">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.  Could someone please give me some idea how I can achieve this scrolling effect in my div?  Thanks.

Comment: are you just trying to make it put the panel on top when you click it?

Comment: I am trying to take the entire code format and use it as a fixed sized accordion menu to be displayed on my left side bar of the web page.  Yes, the panel should move to the top of the accordion followed by its listed items when the user clicks on the panel.  The rest of the collapsed panels on top or below this panel should scroll out of view if there is no space for it to be displayed in the accordion.  Thank you.